# Get TextBox Value in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Anyone one please tell me with example ,how to get textbox value in View Model, My model property is already Binding with textbox with Mode Two Way

[image]

This is my view model functions, I want to add new record to my observable collection.

C#

```
public void AddPerson()
{
  // add new record
}

private Model.Person _PersonData;
public Model.Person PersonData
{
    get {
        if(_PersonData==null)
        {
            _PersonData = new Person();
        }
        return _PersonData;
        }
    set
    {
        Setproperty(ref this._PersonData, value);
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:Demo.ViewModel"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:Demo.Model" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="438" Width="664"
    GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"              
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Model:Person x:Key="PersonDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
    <VM:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModelDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

   <Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <!--<Button Content="settings" />-->
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="20"
               Height="20"
               Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_futurama_fry}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="Karthik" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>


<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModelDataSource}}">
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFBF9F9" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F6F6" Offset="0.555"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Border BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="388" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="636" CornerRadius="3">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.168,0.166" StartPoint="0.168,0.08">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF39D5FF" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Label Content="Master Details" Margin="10,1,502,352" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>

    <Border BorderBrush="#FFC7C2C2" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="238" Margin="21,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187" CornerRadius="3">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.433,0.407" StartPoint="0.435,0.134">
                <GradientStop Color="#29c5ff" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFC7C2C2" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="239" Margin="227,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405" CornerRadius="3">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.435,0.378" StartPoint="0.435,0.134">
                <GradientStop Color="#29c5ff" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Button Content="DELETE" Margin="211,189,41,21" Width="149" Height="21"/>
    </Border>
    <Label Content="New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="37,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Foreground="White"/>
    <Label Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="246,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" Foreground="White"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="37,150,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonDataSource}}"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="37,197,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=ID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonDataSource}}"/>
    <Button Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="37,291,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding _addCommand}" Content="edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="272,291,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149"/>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Margin="246,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366"  ItemsSource="{Binding MasterData}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Name" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>  
                        </DataTemplate>   
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>    
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Location" Width="125">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="37,241,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Location,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonDataSource}}"/>

</Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: add it in your question

Comment: I want to add new record to my observablecollection

Comment: just add the object ti the collection

Comment: NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true,NotifyOnTArgetUpdated=true will help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I could not use your code snippet to reproduce your issue accurately. So I have made a simple code sample to achieve your target as you described. I believe you would get some useful information form it and check your code to solve your problem.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition>

        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition>

        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding name,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Id,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding location,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>

        <Button Content="add new" Command="{Binding AddNew}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding persons}" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Margin="10 0 0 0"></TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" Margin="20 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
class MainViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> persons { get; set; }

    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    private string _Id;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    private string _location;

    public string location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set { _location = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("location");
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand AddNew { get; set; }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        persons = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>();
        persons.Add(new PersonModel() {Name="test1",ID="123",Location="u.s." });
        AddNew = new RelayCommand(AddNewPerson);
    }

    private void AddNewPerson()
    {
        PersonModel p = new PersonModel() {Name=name,ID=Id,Location=location };
        persons.Add(p);
    }
}
```

PersonModel.cs

```
class PersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

[image]